# VMware or Docker containers for TeamCity CI

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, teamcity

We have a setup of 200 VM's as Build Agents, working with TeamCity. We are thinking of saving the VMware License cost moving to Docker. Anyone having any prior experience on which would provide better performance?

My goal is not to compromise with performance, but if Docker gives even same performance as VMware, we'll switch to docker.

My build agent VM's runs on either windows or ubuntu. Builds on linux uses mainly Python, and windows system mainly uses Visual Studio (different versions). We'll be doing performance test ourselves, but I want to know if someone has done this before and experienced any benefits.

Comment: Someone flagged this to be closed ("primarily opinion-based"). I'd edit it to be a more specific, and more technical question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently built my own ephemeral docker container build agents. I've been using them for about 4 months building for 25+ different projects. The dependency management is so much nicer than having different VM's running your build agent. You also have the option to have many build agents running on a single VM. I did not see a performance decrease when I switched from VM's to docker build agents. Using a swarm manager it is very easy to spin up more or less agents depending on your need.

If you are interested I also have a helpful script that automates authorizing a new agent from Docker. TeamCity has no way to automatically authorize an agent, it seems to have to be done through the API.

TL;DR Docker build agents are much easier to use, less overhead and ephemeral with no (visible) performance decrease.

Comment: Is there somewhere to check out that automated authorization? I'm looking at setting up automated agent management using the jetbrains teamcity-agent docker images as a base, but right now, any time I rebuild the images (I'm prepackaging some compiled build essentials), I have to reauth the agents, which is a pain